# codeigniter zip crashes the zip file content

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, zip

I’m using this…

```
$resumePath = APPPATH."../public/uploads/resume/";

//print_r($fileNames);
//Array ( [0] => 1.docx [1] => 1.docx [2] => 3.docx [3] => 4.docx [4] => 5.docx [5] => 7.docx [6] => 8.docx [7] => 9.docx [8] => 10.docx [9] => 10.docx )

        $this->load->library('zip');
        foreach ($fileNames as $files) {
            if (is_file($resumePath . $files)) {
                $this->zip->read_file($resumePath . $files);
            }
        }
        $this->zip->download('backup.zip');
```

It works fine, but when i try to unzip with Winzip or Winrar. it show me:

`C:\Users\User\Downloads\backup.zip: The archive is either in unknown format or damaged`

[image]

**Zip File Curruped is Solved but now I am getting the file is currupted inside the zip archive...i mean after extracting when i open the doxc file its showing me file is currupted or damaged..and one more thing the size of the doxc file is now showing `45` or `55` where as when downloading with `read_file` the size is showing properly(ex: in the image above)..but now its showing only two digit number...please help any one..**

Updated Code:

the below code allow me to extract but when i open docx file it shows file is damaged::

```
 foreach ($fileNames as $files) {
            if (is_file($resumePath . $files)) {
                **$this->zip->add_data($files, $resumePath . $files);**
            }
        }
```

the below code showing right size of the file but not allowing me to extract the file:

```
foreach ($fileNames as $files) {
            if (is_file($resumePath . $files)) {
                **$this->zip->add_data($files, file_get_contents($resumePath . $files));**
            }
        }
```

any ideas.. would be a great help... thanks in advance

Comment: What are `$resumePath` and `$files` variables? I don't see them in your code.

Comment: Does your script echo or print anything else? Also check for extra whitespace before and after the php tags that could be getting sent to the browser.

Comment: @HashemQolami Sir look at the first line for `resumePath` and second and third line for `filename`

Comment: @kumar_v Sir as of now  i have all the docx file size and content same but with different name..

Comment: try adding `exit()` `die()` or something after the $this->zip->download, maybe it is still executing other scripts after download thats why the corrupted file

Comment: @tomexsans Sir.. i tried what you have suggested..but still same curuupted file..